# jQuery: slideDown() showing wrong divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 different divs I want to show for 4 different buttons. So when the uesr clicks a specific link, a specific div will show up. 
This is my HTML:

**Links:**

```
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a id="clickme1">I'm Interested</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a id="clickme2">I'm Interested</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a id="clickme3">I'm Interested</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a id="clickme4">I'm Interested</a>
    </div>
```

**My Divs:**

```
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad1">
    <p>Show Table Here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad2">
    <p>Show Table Here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad3">
    <p>Show Table Here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad4">
    <p>Show Table Here</p>
    </div>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$("#clickme1").click(function () {
    if ($("#ad1").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#ad1").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#ad1").hide();
    }
});

// Ad 2
$("#clickme2").click(function () {
    if ($("#ad2").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#ad2").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#ad2").hide();
    }
});

// Ad 3
$("#clickme3").click(function () {
    if ($("#ad3").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#ad3").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#ad3").hide();
    }
});

//Ad 4
$("#clickme4").click(function () {
    if ($("#ad4").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#ad4").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $("#ad4").hide();
    }
});
```

In my CSS, all 4 divs have the attribute display:none.

**Problem**

When I click on my links, 1 by 1, they all show fine. But if I click on any other link to start with, it always shows the first div (#ad1). 
This is the same when I want to hide them, if I click on any of them again, it hides another div. There must be an obvious step I am missing! Please help :(

Comment: Can you put in a jsfiddle please and Ill take a look

Comment: 1. when you click on link, you must prevent default behaviour: `e.preventDefault();`+ your code is too big and Copy Pasted -> try to use another selectors/methods in JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using Bootstrap, I was using the same div that had the col-3 width (class) and then I was hiding that using the id #ad1 etc, when it was hidden, it had no width, so when I was calling the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th div, they were showing at the beginning because there was nothing aligning the divs into their place since the others had no width! 
This was not a jQuery problem, just simple Bootstrap/HTML :( 
Sorry and thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making all `id`s, rather use a class. Then add a `data-slid-id` to the link, that is the id that should slide down or up.

When adding extra links and tables, you don't need an extra function.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ad1,#ad2,#ad3,#ad4').hide();
  $('.clickme').on('click',function() {
      $('#'+$(this).data('slide-id')).slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a class="clickme" data-slide-id="ad1">I'm Interested</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a class="clickme" data-slide-id="ad2">I'm Interested</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a class="clickme" data-slide-id="ad3">I'm Interested</a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center">
    <a class="clickme" data-slide-id="ad4">I'm Interested</a>
</div>



<div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad1">
    <p>Show Table Here 1</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad2">
    <p>Show Table Here 2</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad3">
    <p>Show Table Here 3</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="ad4">
    <p>Show Table Here 4</p>
</div>
```